# Brother Scanner ADS-2700W brsaneconfig4: command not found

Tags: drivers, scanner, brother

I'm trying to set up an ADS-2700W.  Why does brsaneconfig not work?  Do I need to install a different version on libjpeg8?

```
user@hostname:~$ sudo dpkg -i --force-all brscanads2200ads2700w-0.1.15-1.amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package brscanads2200ads2700w.
(Reading database ... 95891 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack brscanads2200ads2700w-0.1.15-1.amd64.deb ...
libjpeg8 is required.
Unpacking brscanads2200ads2700w (0.1.15-1) ...
Setting up brscanads2200ads2700w (0.1.15-1) ...
user@hostname:~$ dpkg -l | grep Brother
ii  brscanads2200ads2700w                0.1.15-1                           amd64        Brother Scanner Driver
user@hostname:~$ brsaneconfig4
brsaneconfig4: command not found
user@hostname:~$ brsaneconfig3
brsaneconfig3: command not found
user@hostname:~$ brsaneconfig2
brsaneconfig2: command not found
user@hostname:~$ brsaneconfig
brsaneconfig: command not found
user@hostname:~$ brsaneconfig5
brsaneconfig5: command not found
user@hostname:~$ dpkg -l | grep libjpeg
ii  libjpeg-dev:amd64                    8c-2ubuntu8                        amd64        Independent JPEG Group's JPEG runtime library (dependency package)
ii  libjpeg-turbo8:amd64                 2.0.3-0ubuntu1.20.04.1             amd64        IJG JPEG compliant runtime library.
ii  libjpeg-turbo8-dev:amd64             2.0.3-0ubuntu1.20.04.1             amd64        Development files for the IJG JPEG library
ii  libjpeg8:amd64                       8c-2ubuntu8                        amd64        Independent JPEG Group's JPEG runtime library (dependency package)
ii  libjpeg8-dev:amd64                   8c-2ubuntu8                        amd64        Independent JPEG Group's JPEG runtime library (dependency package)
user@hostname:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
user@hostname:~$ sudo brsaneconfig4
[sudo] password for user:
sudo: brsaneconfig4: command not found
user@hostname:~$ sudo -s
root@hostname:/home/user# brsaneconfig4
brsaneconfig4: command not found
```

Comment: What makes you think you need the `brsaneconfig` command?

Comment: Fantastic question.  I just added an answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it turns out I had thought I read Brother's instructions, but I wasn't careful enough.  I was working with an ADS-1000W previously and had assumed the setup process was the same for the ADS-1000W and the ADS-2700W.

It's not.

For the ADS-1000W:
`brsaneconfig4 -a name=(name your device) model=(model name) ip=xx.xx.xx.xx`

For the ADS-2700W: `sudo conf_ip 192.168.xxx.xxx`

It works now.

Also, official Brother support didn't tell me this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, that this driver provides the brsaneconfig commands.

As far as I remember (this driver is rather old) you should be able to check if your device is recognized by executing `scanimage -L`

If your scanner does not work after successful installation, you might add the "lp" group to your user.

I guess you looked up the [FAQ](https://www.brother.is/support/ads-2700w/faqs/setup-settings/faq00100725_000) from brother..

Comment: Updated question with sudo test.  That doesn't help.  
`scanimage -L` won't find the scanner since I haven't set it up with `brsaneconfig`.

Comment: Sorry, I revised my answer, the sudo part was crap.  Since the driver is no brsane driver, the brsaneconfig commands will NOT be provided....